# What ASCII character to use for "align center"?

Tags: tables, symbols, command-line

If I use `<` to represent the setting "align left" and `>` to represent the setting "align right" what symbol should I use for "align center"? Is there any *de facto* standard for this?  The symbol has to be an [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) character the user can type on a [US keyboard layout](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:KB_United_States.svg).

## Context

I am working on the command line interface of a console application for Unix-like operating systems that can output pseudographical tables, like so:

```
┌─────┬─────┬────────┬─────┐
│ PID │ TTY │  TIME  │ CMD │
├─────┼─────┼────────┼─────┤
│ 8580│pts/1│00:00:00│  ps │
├─────┼─────┼────────┼─────┤
│28075│pts/1│00:00:01│ zsh │
└─────┴─────┴────────┴─────┘
```

The application can be told to align the text in each column left, right or center. To make it do that the user gives it the command line option `-align LIST` where `LIST` is a list of words "left", "right" or "center" where each word corresponds to one column, e.g., `-align 'left left right center'`.

I found that having to write each word in full takes too much effort. I intend to introduce *l* (a small *L*), *r* and *c* as shortcuts (which has precedent in [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX)) but I also want to offer another, more graphical set of shortcut characters that would be easier to understand at a glace, say, when reading a shell script. Since using *<*, *>* for "left" and "right" respectively seems inevitable I am looking for the third unknown symbol to go with those two.

Comment: How about `-` or `^`?

Comment: Or pipe |. I'd mix pipe with brackets, like bookends.   [ | ]

Comment: + looks nice and symmetrical: <+>. I would use letters, like in Latex table formatting: l c r. Pipe (|) means vertical divider (bar), & is column separator.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe "|"? (That's shift-backslash.)

Answer (score 1):

^ might be read as 'up'

| might be read as 'concatenate' or 'OR' or a cell boundary

How about using #

Answer (score 1):

`<` means "left-side padding is smaller than right-side padding"
`>` means "left-side padding is larger than right-side padding"
So to express "left-side padding is equal to right-side padding", I would use `=`.

It has the benefit of already being related to `<` and `>`, and it looks roughly similar but with clear differences. It also doesn't imply any other direction (like up or down), but rather a balance, which is precisely what we want.

Other symbols I might consider are `#`, `*`, `¤`, and `_`, but I think that `=` would be the most obvious in context.

Comment: The equals sign `=` looks a bit like two lines of text – **justified** ones. Even though justification is not (yet) to be supported, `|` and other vertical characters, incl. `!` and `$`, seem more appropriate, at least by graphic analogy. The generic currency symbol `¤` is neither easy to type nor in US-ASCII.

Comment: @Crissov maybe I'm misunderstanding, but how would you ever justify text in a CLI (especially since there hasn't even been mention of multi-line support)? Using a thin, vertical character (even if they are "centered") for a horizontal setting seems like it would be less effective. My bad on `¤`, though.

Comment: You could justify with multiple space characters instead of one. It won’t be useful most of the time, though.

Answer (score 1):

What about

**< T >**

or

**< ǁ >**

Comment: Could you add some reasoning why T or || would be a good choice?

Comment: Sure, it visually looks like center of something.

Answer (score 0):

You should go for one of the keys close by.

[image]

A good example for this is Mac Text Editor. The shortcuts in the editor for text alignment are as below. If you check the keyboard, the three keys **{ } |** lie together in a similar way.

[image]

It is important to understand that, text formatting shortcuts can be dependent on the OS. For example, [Evernote](https://evernote.com) keeps the text alignment shortcuts similar to Microsoft Office for their Windows version ([source](https://help.evernote.com/hc/en-us/articles/209004807-Keyboard-shortcuts-in-Evernote-for-Windows)) while it provides shortcuts similar to MacOS Text Editor for Mac users ([source](https://help.evernote.com/hc/en-us/articles/208313358)).